# Python Flask paginate error:paginated page returned 404

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pagination

#### error source code:

https://github.com/wedojava/exloger

---

#### Expected Behavior

There is a form with email and ip  at index for search and show response, the response should be paginated.

`main/routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, g, current_app, session
from app.main import bp
from app.main.forms import SearchForm

@bp.before_app_request
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        current_user.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()

    try:
        session['email'] = session['email'] if session['email'] else 'example@example.com'
    except KeyError as ke:
        session['email'] = 'example@example.com'


@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        words_email = ["%" + form.email.data + "%"]
        rule_email = and_(*[LogImported.sender_address.like(w) for w in words_email])
        # pay attention these two lines below:
        l = LogImported.query.filter(rule_email)
        pagination = l.paginate(page, per_page=50, error_out=True)
        pageitems = pagination.items
        session['email'] = form.email.data
        return render_template('index.html', title=_('Home'), form=form, loglist = l, \
        pageitems = pageitems, pagination = pagination)
    elif session['email'] is not 'example@example.com':
        words_email = ["%" + form.email.data + "%"]
        rule_email = and_(*[LogImported.sender_address.like(w) for w in words_email])
        # pay attention these two lines below:
        l = LogImported.query.filter(rule_email)
        pagination = l.paginate(page, per_page=50, error_out=True)
        pageitems = pagination.items
        session['email'] = form.email.data
        return render_template('index.html', title=_('Home'), form=form, loglist = l, \
        pageitems = pageitems, pagination = pagination)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', title=_('Home'), form=form)
```

`main/forms.py`:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(_l('Email'))
    ip = StringField('IP', validators=[Length(min=0, max=140)])
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Submit'))
```

`main/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from app.main import routes
```

`/models.py`:

```
class LogImported(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sender_address = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
    recipient_address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    recipient_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    return_path = db.Column(db.String(255))
    client_hostname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    client_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    server_hostname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    server_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    original_client_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    original_server_ip = db.Column(db.String(100))
    event_id = db.Column(db.String(50))
    total_bytes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    connector_id = db.Column(db.String(50))
    message_subject = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

`templates/index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from 'bootstrap/form.html' import render_form %}
{% from 'bootstrap/pagination.html' import render_pagination %}


...

{{ render_pagination(pagination) }}

...
```

#### Actual Behavior

In short, get result from index's form then paginated,but any paginated links cannot work right.

I set email and ip to session as `session['email']` and `session['ip']`.
Then,I click page 2,search these keywords by session to a object and paginate,but `paginate()` cannot work right, link like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index?page=2`,response an error page:404.

`elif` in routes.py:

```
l = LogImported.query.filter(rule)
pagination = l.paginate(page, per_page=50, error_out=True)
```

Return type of `l = LogImported.query.filter(rule)` is right, but `l.paginate(page, per_page=50, error_out=True)` throw an error.
code blocked by if is work right, by in elif,same code response error.

parameter `rule` is same at these two place. Why these bug raised?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2018 12:44:51] "GET /index?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

#### Environment

- Python version: 3.7.1
- Flask version:1.0.2
- Werkzeug version:0.14.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens when you request a page number that is higher than the number of pages existent with the filtered results. In this case, you're requesting page number 2, with "l.paginate(page, per_page=50, error_out=True)" (page=2) when in fact the number of results is less or equal than 50, so you only get one page.

This is a common mistake, the ui is requesting a page number higher than the existent. On every search, you got to reset the page to 1.

Look the image below, the behavior is the same (but I got the flag error_out=False so the pagination return the results with the items empty even though I get 6 items with the search).

[image]

Comment: hey, so you, the great man here, it useful for me , tons of thanks to you!

Comment: @wedojava use pycharm debugger in order to check line line code execution. It will give you more info about the error.